# Duplicate Rows (OBJECTS) after setting DGV Data Source [C#]

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, binding, datasource

I am having a hard time solving this issue. I have an Object of called Section, I am adding this Section object to a list, then the list is used as the Data Grid View Data Source. When I add the object to the list, everything is good, when I set the DataGridView datasource, and display it on the grid everything is normal. When I add another Object of type Section, as soon as the List is set as the grid datasource, the grid will display 2 objects, but both are the same as the first object added. Adding a third object does the same behavior and so on. What could be causing this ? changing the datasource list when it is binded to the datagridview ?

Here is the part in which the Object gets set

```
    private void AddSectionButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {

            var documentType = MopDocument.DocumentType;
            var sections = FillAssemblyInformation(documentType.DllPath);
            if (sections == null || sections.Count <= 0)
                return;

            var addSectionForm = new MopSectionAddEditForm(sections);
            var dialog = addSectionForm.ShowDialog();
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;

            var addedSection = addSectionForm.AddedEditedMopSection;

            var sectionsList = dgvSelectedSections.DataSource as BindingList<MopSection>;
            if (sectionsList == null || sectionsList.Count == 0) {
                sectionsList = new BindingList<MopSection>();
                addedSection.SequenceNumber = 1;
            } else {
                var lastLevel = sectionsList[sectionsList.Count - 1].SequenceNumber;
                addedSection.SequenceNumber = lastLevel + 1;
            }

            sectionsList.Add(addedSection); 



            // I looped this list to check what objects are being added, and it is correct.
            dgvSelectedSections.DataSource = null;
            dgvSelectedSections.DataSource = sectionsList;
            // I looped again on the list and now the objects are duplicated to the first element that was added to the list



            dgvSelectedSections.Rows[dgvSelectedSections.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.ShowErrorDialog("EXception Occured", ex);
        }
    }
```

Please if you have any information on why this is happening let me know

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, This was happening due to wrong check in the .Equals method that was Overridden in the Section Objects